# Arc length between two satellites

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit, low-earth-orbit, terminology, starlink

When considering two satellites in the same **circular** orbit, is it correct to say: The *arc length* between the satellites is...? Is there a more appropriate term when talking about the curved distance between the satellites? I don't want to talk about the angle between them but about the actual distance on the circle.

Comment: Isn't this the same question asked yesterday? [Distance between two satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55418/distance-between-two-satellites)

Comment: There is no answer there, it is the right term to use in a sentence or if there is another term.